# Get edge weight by vertices id

Tags: python, igraph

I want to perform get edges weight, but I am having problems.

First, I tried this:

```
from igraph import *
g = Nexus.get("karate")
weight = g.es[g.get_eid(vertex, neighbor)]['weight']
```

But, if edge not exist igraph return erro. I want, for instance, that only returns -1

Second, there is operation/function computationally more efficient than this from IGRAPH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like this:

```
from igraph import *
g = Nexus.get("karate")
weight = g.es.select(_source=0, _target=1)['weight']
print weight
```

This returns empty set when there isn't edge.

Comment: using `_source` and/or _`target` for undirected graphs does not work in the python interface. See https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/issues/30.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is a keyword for that in the `get_eid` method:

```
get_eid(v1, v2, directed=True, error=True)

@param error: if C{True}, an exception will be raised when the
  given edge does not exist. If C{False}, -1 will be returned in
  that case.
```

So, in your case that means:

```
weight = g.es[g.get_eid(vertex, neighbor, error=False)]['weight']
```